# request.get() is getting stuck

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Hello I am trying to scrape some data from a website and request.get() is getting caught up on something.
here is my code:

```
page_url = front_end+str(i)+'/'
page = requests.get(page_url)
```

so I want it to be a string, because I am just entering an url and if I stop the code or it runs too long I get something like:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", 
line 377, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 24, in <module>
    page = requests.get(page_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, inbegin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 258, in_read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1002, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 865, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 625, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
```

I do not understand what the `TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'` means or how to fix it.

Comment: At first glance it looks like you're using an old version of urllib3 that isn't compatible with Python 3. What version of `requests` library did you install? `pip install requests` and/or `pip install urllib3` may fix it.

Comment: Separately you may want to look into something like Pipenv (https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/) to manage dependencies in a way where multiple Python apps' dependencies won't collide with each other.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried your commands but pip didn't update anything. This code worked approximately 6 months ago but now I cannot get requests to function.

Comment: Sorry, maybe try a `pip install --upgrade requests`? I should have typed that the first time.

Comment: UPDATE: turns out my request was getting blocked and had to add an header to requests and now the program works!

Comment: What a weird way for that error to manifest itself…but glad to hear you got it working!

Comment: @TylerStrouth, if you found a working solution, write up an answer to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer:

Sometimes requests from requests.get() gets blocked by server, so solution is to make the server think the request is coming from a web browser.
Example:

```
 headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36',}
 page = requests.get("https://example.com", headers=headers)
```